# Aerobic capacity standards/classifications

Tags: running, cardio, bicycling

Most strength sports have classifications and standards to assist athletes in the assessment of their current performance level. For example, these are the standards for men, ordered by weight class, for RAW Powerlifting (squat, bench and deadlift):

[image: USPA Standards in pounds for Men RAW]

Is there anything similar for aerobic exercise? For example, what are decent times for a 400 m sprint, for a 5k run, or for a century ride?

Comment: This should be asked in the sports forum.

Comment: Just a note on the close votes that it's "unclear what's being asked", he very clearly is asking for speed standards on various distances. Maybe there's some other problems, but clarity doesn't seem like the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most accurate option for measuring aerobic capacity would be performing an VO2 max test. Since this procedure requires complex medical equipment, a number of ways have been developed to estimate this rate.

One of them is the Cooper test, in which you run for 12 minutes to maximal effort. Then, you obtain a VO2 max based on this equation:

[image: Cooper test equation to calculate VO2 max]

Here is a table with the expected levels of performance according to age (from [here](https://www.topendsports.com/testing/norms/vo2max.htm)):

[image: Aerobic capacity standards]

[More tests](https://www.topendsports.com/testing/tests/index.htm) exists to estimate your VO2 max like the multi-stage fitness test or the Rockport fitness walking test.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely - that table is based on algorithm. For running it would not be that easy. I would look for something based on statistics. At school, we ware supposed to do particular number of reps, or run in particular time limit to get a score. So I've searched for `1000m run test results` and one of the results is [this page](https://www.justrunlah.com/the-2-4km-test-for-vo2-max-calculation/). Hope that is what you ware looking for - at least you have a table. :)